# k8s dashboard ( v2.0.0-betaX )on arm device

Tags: kubernetes, raspberry-pi, arm, dashboard, k3s

I have a 2-raspberry Pi 4 kubernetes Cluster. It uses k3s : (https://github.com/rancher/k3s) which is built on k8s 1.16.

I want to install k8s dashboard (https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard)

However the last arm-compile image is the v1.10.1 which is not compatible with k8s-1.16 .

Is there a (un)official image of K8s dahsboard v2.0.0-betaX compiled for arm ?

Or someone had any tips on how to compile such an arm image ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article on docker blog](https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-official-images-now-multi-platform/)  docker supports multi platform images since September 2017.

Kubernetes dashboard images are already supporting multiple architectures so you don't need to build it by yourself.

Take a look at the image below.

[image]

You can use `kubernetesui/dashboard` tag and your docker daemon should pull appropriate image for your architecture.

Let me know if it helped.